# How to only replace the vowels of words that match the words in a given array with a "*"?

Tags: regex, ruby

I need to create a ruby method that accepts a string and an array and if any of the words in the string matches the words in the given array then all the vowels of the matched words in the string should be replaced with a "*". I have tried to do this using regex and an "if condition" but I don't know why this does not work. I'd really appreciate if somebody could explain me where I have gone wrong and how I can get this code right.

```
def censor(sentence, arr)
    if arr.include? sentence.downcase
      sentence.downcase.gsub(/[aeiou]/, "*")
    end
end


puts censor("Gosh, it's so hot", ["gosh", "hot", "shoot", "so"])

#expected_output = "G*sh, it's s* h*t"
```

Answer (score 1):

`are.include? sentence.downcase` reads, “If one of the elements of `arr` equals `sentence.downcase` ...”, not what you want.

```
baddies = ["gosh", "it's", "hot", "shoot", "so"]
sentence = "Gosh, it's so very hot"

r = /\b#{baddies.join('|')}\b/i
  #=> /\bgosh|it's|hot|shoot|so\b/i 
sentence.gsub(r) { |w| w.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '*') }
  #=> "G*sh *t's s* very h*t"
```

In the regular expression, `\b` is a *word break* and `#{baddies.join('|')}` requires a match of one of the `baddies`. The  word breaks are to avoid, for example, `"so"` matching `"solo"` or `"possible"`. One could alternatively write:

```
/\b#{Regexp.union(baddies).source}\b/
  #=> /\bgosh|it's|hot|shoot|so\b/
```

See [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) and [Regexp#source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-source). `source` is needed because `Regexp.union(baddies)` is unaffected by the case-indifference modifier (`i`).

Another approach is split the sentence into words, manipulate each word, then rejoin all the pieces to form a new sentence. One difficulty with this approach concerns the character `"'"`, which serves double-duty as a single quote and an apostrophe. Consider

```
sentence = "She liked  the song, 'don't box me in'"
baddies = ["don't"]
```

the approach I've given here yields the correct result:

```
r = /\b#{baddies.join('|')}\b/i
  #=> /\bdon't\b/i 
sentence.gsub(r) { |w| w.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '*') }
  #=> "She liked the song 'd*n't box me in'"
```

If we instead divide up the sentence into parts we might try the following:

```
sentence.split(/([\p{Punct}' ])/)
  #=> ["She", " ", "liked", " ", "", " ", "the", " ", "song", ",", "",
  #    " ", "", "'", "don", "'", "t", " ", "box", " ", "me", " ", "in", "'"]
```

As seen, the regex split `"don't"` into `"don"` and `"'t"`, not what we want. Clearly, distinguishing between single quotes and apostrophes is a non-trivial task. This is made difficult by the the fact that words can begin or end with apostrophes (`"'twas"`) and most nouns in the possessive form that end with `"s"` are followed by an apostrophe (`"Chris' car"`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not return any value if the condition is valid.

One option is to split words by spaces and punctuation, manipulate, then rejoin:

```
def censor(sentence, arr)
  words = sentence.scan(/[\w'-]+|[.,!?]+/) # this splits the senctence into an array of words and punctuation
  res = []
  words.each do |word|
    word = word.gsub(/[aeiou]/, "*") if arr.include? word.downcase
    res << word
  end
  res.join(' ') # add spaces also before punctuation
end


puts censor("Gosh, it's so hot", ["gosh", "hot", "shoot", "so"])
#=> G*sh , it's s* h*t
```

Note that `res.join(' ')` add spaces also before punctuation. I'm not so good with regexp, but this could solve:

```
res.join(' ').gsub(/ [.,!?]/) { |punct| "#{punct}".strip }
#=> G*sh, it's s* h*t
```

This part `words = sentence.scan(/[\w'-]+|[.,!?]+/)` returns `["Gosh", ",", "it's", "so", "hot"]`